# Apache virtual host https for remote connections http for local connections

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I successfully setup an Apache that acts as reverse proxy (with basic auth and https) for a service running on a machine in my local network.

Connecting from the internet works fine but if i want to connect from lan some clients (e.g. java based) have problems with to connect (certificate problem).

Because of that and for convenience i want allow local machines to connect via http and without basic auth. How to achieve this?

This are my current virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    #ServerName www.example.com:80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin gmail.com
    ServerName <some domain>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
    <Location />    
        AuthUserFile "...passwd.txt"
        AuthName "secured"
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

        Alias /.well-known C:/xampp/htdocs/.well-known

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "...chain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "...key.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "...-crt.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

The first one is needed to renew the letsencrypt certificate. the second one is the one i want to open for local machines (http without basic auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same proxy directives but with a  block restricting by IP address or network. Add something similar, plus any other directives that are required, to the following to your port 80 vhost:

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8082/
<Location />
   require ip <local network in CIDR notation>
</Location>